# how ot get value of array object in jQuery

Tags: jquery

can any one let me know how to get value of "ID" which is 6 from following array object in jQuery/Javascipt.

```
[Object {name="mode", value="Add"}, 
 Object {name="test", value="abc"}, 
 Object {name="ID", value="6"}]
```

Comment: This is not a valid Javascript's array.

Comment: i have [{"name":"mode","value":"Add"},{"name":"test","value":"abc"},{"name":"ID","value":"6"}] but it is in form of string i have just parse it  by jQuery.parseJSON and i got above formate but i need value of ID which is dynamic.

Comment: Thanks all i got solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You can loop the array and search for `ID` in the objects.

```js
// your object
var arr = [
    {name: "mode", value: "Add"}, 
    {name: "test", value: "abc"}, 
    {name: "ID", value: "6"}
];

// the default value, whenever 'ID' is not found
var value = null;

// loop the array and search
for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
    if( arr[i].name === "ID" ) {
        value = arr[i].value;
    }
}

// your result :)
console.log(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through your array and find an object with a required `name`.
The easiest way to do this is to utilize `Array.prototype.filter` - you can filter an array out and leave only this object which has `name` equal to `ID` (assuming that there is always exactly one such object), and then returns its value.

```js
var arr = [{ "name": "mode", "value": "Add" }, { "name": "test", "value": "abc" }, { "name": "ID", "value": "6" }];

// pre-ES6 syntax
var id = arr.filter(function(x) { return x.name === 'ID'; })[0].value; 
console.log(id);

// ES6 syntax
var id = arr.filter(x => x.name === 'ID')[0].value;
console.log(id);
```

This code is not complete, you may want to check for `filter` result length or make an universal method:

```js
var arr = [{ "name": "mode", "value": "Add" }, { "name": "test", "value": "abc" }, { "name": "ID", "value": "6" }];
   
function getParameter(obj, param) {
  var foundParams = obj.filter(function(x) { 
    return x.name === param 
  });
  
  if (foundParams.length == 0)  
    return null;
  
  if (foundParams.length > 1)
    throw new Error('Invalid object: more than one parameter ' + param);
  
  return foundParams[0].value;
}

console.log(getParameter(arr, 'ID'));
console.log(getParameter(arr, 'test'));
console.log(getParameter(arr, 'mode'));
console.log(getParameter(arr, 'notexists'));
```

Comment: Filter will return an array not an object

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Thanks, I have fixed this now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ar your_array =[
 {name :"mode", value:"Add"}, 
 {name :"test", value:"abc"}, 
 {name :"ID", value:"6"}
 ];

$.each( your_array, function( key, value ) {

  if(key=="ID")
  {
  var your_Value = value; //6
  }
});
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.